# Merging and Adding MySQL Rows?

Tags: mysql

Here's an example of what's in my table:

```
id, domain, revenue, traffic
1, example.com, 0.01, 500
2, example.com, 0.01, 250
3, stackoverflow.com, 0.01, 400
4, example.com, 0.01, 350
5, stackoverflow.com, 0.01, 500
```

I basically want to select/merge rows based upon the domain column.  For example, I'd want to output this from the above:

```
domain, revenue, traffic
example.com, 0.03, 1100
stackoverflow.com, 0.02, 900
```

Comment: Basic SQL: SUM and GROUP BY

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this:

Select domain, sum(revenue),sum(traffic) from table
group by domain;